# Is there any sample code for developing the Cardscanning(CSSN) using PHP?

Tags: php, image-scanner

I want to develop a module for card scanning using [CSSN](http://www.card-reader.com/).They gave the sample code for another languages like C#,Delphi etc.(except PHP).
Is there any sample code for scanning the document using PHP with this CSSN device?
Whether we can develop application for this scanner using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their website, and based on the fact that they're using ActiveX controls, I get the feeling you'll never get this working on a language that doesn't use Microsoft's runtime.  Even if you were able to somehow get it working, I doubt you would get much support from them on it.

I would recommend, instead, writing a program in a language they support that can in turn talk to your PHP application.  As the SDK sends events to your intermediate app it can send them on to your PHP program, and the PHP program can send commands to the SDK through the intermediate app.

Comment: Thanks for your support.I got another thing from their website.That is http://www.card-reader.com/scan_to_web_ids.htm .So it is better I think?

Comment: As long as you're willing to restrict your users to Internet Explorer, then yes.  Instead of talking to your web server, this application populates fields in a form on the user's browser.  

You web application has no connection to it, though you may need to name your fields in some special way so it can identify them.